# Trying to translate specific Data Science terms to Traditional Chinese

Tags: translation, terminology

I am translating a paragraph to Traditional Chinese about Data Science.

The subject is **Decision Modeling** which is translated in Google as:決策建模
The term I am having a problem with is: **Quantitative Decision Science**.
This term is translated as:定量決策科學

But, actually I am not sure if either of these terms are correct.

Can someone please advise me on this? Do the above Chinese terms make sense, or is there a more accurate way to translate these terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Quantitative Decision Science = **定量化决策科学**

[CUFE](http://mse.cufe.edu.cn/info/1493/5734.htm)

> 最优化方法是运筹学（72学时）课程的延续，是一门定量化决策科学，它利用现代数学、计算机以及其它科学的成果建立模型，研究人类从事各种活动中处理事物的数量化规律，使有限的资源得到合理利用，以获得尽可能满意的经济效益和社会效益。
>
> Optimization Method is the continue class of Operations Research. This is a quantitative decision science which builds models to study the quantitative law of people’s activities in order to make rational use of the limited resources and to obtain the approving economic and social efficiency based on modern mathematics, computer and other academic achievements.

[School of Management Science and Engineering](https://www.heshengjcb.com/info/1493/5749.html)

> 运筹学是一门定量化决策科学，它利用现代数学、计算机以及其它科学的成果建立模型，研究人类从事各种活动中处理事物的数量化规律，使有限的资源得到合理利用，以获得尽可能满意的经济效益和社会效益。
>
> Operations Research is a quantitative decision science which builds models to study the quantitative law of people’s activities in order to make rational use of the limited resources and to obtain the approving economic and social efficiency based on modern mathematics, computer and other academic achievements.

Comment: Thanks very much. I appreciate it! Great answer. So, the other term "Decision Modeling" is ok the way I had it translated? "決策建模"

Comment: @JoeT.Boka There's a reference for "DMN或Decision Modeling Notation（决策建模符号）" as a translation. But I've also seen "決策模式" as a translation for "Decision Modeling."

Comment: That's great. Thanks again. I appreciate it.